# How to use loguru with standard loggers?

Tags: python, logging, loguru

I would like to use [Loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) to intercept loggers from other modules.

Could anyone of you tell how to approach this topic, please?

**Example:**

```
import logging
import requests
from loguru import logger

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger_requests = logging.getLogger('requests')
logger_requests.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug('Message through loguru')
requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

**Execution:**

```
$ python test_logger.py  > /dev/null 
2021-03-23 19:35:27.141 | DEBUG    | __main__:<module>:10 - Message through loguru
DEBUG:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): stackoverflow.com:443
DEBUG:https://stackoverflow.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Comment: Have you seen this part in the readme https://github.com/Delgan/loguru#entirely-compatible-with-standard-logging

Comment: Thanks, this is it! 
I missed this line during testing: `logging.basicConfig(handlers=[InterceptHandler()], level=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Answering explicitly...

You want to redirect `requests` logging through [`loguru`](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru).  As mentioned in the comments, you can use:

```py
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[InterceptHandler()], level=0, force=True)
```

However, it's also worth mentioning that decorating functions with `logger.catch()` will vastly improve error tracebacks should anything happen during script execution.

```py
import logging
import sys

import requests
from loguru import logger


class InterceptHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    Add logging handler to augment python stdlib logging.

    Logs which would otherwise go to stdlib logging are redirected through
    loguru.
    """

    @logger.catch(default=True, onerror=lambda _: sys.exit(1))
    def emit(self, record):
        # Get corresponding Loguru level if it exists.
        try:
            level = logger.level(record.levelname).name
        except ValueError:
            level = record.levelno

        # Find caller from where originated the logged message.
        frame, depth = sys._getframe(6), 6
        while frame and frame.f_code.co_filename == logging.__file__:
            frame = frame.f_back
            depth += 1

        logger.opt(depth=depth, exception=record.exc_info).log(level, record.getMessage())


##########################################################################
# The logger.catch() decorator improves error tracebacks
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
##########################################################################
@logger.catch(default=True, onerror=lambda _: sys.exit(1))
def requests_http_get(url=None):
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.basicConfig(handlers=[InterceptHandler()], level=0, force=True)

    logger_requests = logging.getLogger('requests')
    logger_requests.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.debug('Message through loguru')
    requests.get(url)

if __name__=="__main__":
    requests_http_get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```